# How to create numeric routes in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to have a URL path pattern like this:

```
http://example.com/15/232
```

Both first segment and the second segment are composed of integer values. In case this pattern is not met, I want routing to fallback to the default `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}` pattern.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Attribute routing template `"{parameter1:int}/{parameter2:int}"`

Comment: Reference [Routing to Controller Actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd probably do is modify your startup.cs to reflect your new route like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "segment",
        template: "{segment1:int}/{segment2:int}", //<-- Matches /15/232
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Segment" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
}
```

The new route would just point to a single controller and action, and from there, you return the appropriate View for the content based on the path.

```
public IActionResult Segment(int segment1, int segment2)
{

    return View()
}
```